# The postcss is installed differently between npm and yarn

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, postcss

My project has two dependencies: packageA and packageB. The packageA has dependency of `postcss@7.x` while the other one packageB has `postcss@8.x`.

When I used `npm install` the `postcss` installed in the first layer in node_modules would be postcss@8.x.

But when I used `yarn`, some problem popped up. The `postcss` installed at the first layer became `postcss@7.x`.

Actually postcss@8.x installed at first layer node_modules totally met my expectation but yarn did not. What make that difference happen ? How could I fix this when the project has to use `yarn`.